# Volume generated by a revolving Bernoulli Lemniscate - Integral boundary question

Tags: linear-algebra, definite-integrals, volume

The following Lemniscate revolves around the $x$-axis with given values for the boundaries:

$$r^2=9\cos(2\theta)$$
$$ \theta = 0, \pi/4$$

The resulting integral for the volume is also given

$$V_x = \int_{\pi/4}^ 0(r\sin(\theta)^2 (r\cos(\theta))' \, d\theta$$

I was wondering how $\pi/4$ ends up as the bottom boundary in the volume integral. Where as if you would calculate the surface area for the lemniscate it would end up in the top boundary. I have seen boundaries getting switched around several times now and I don't quite understand why. Can anyone give me an easy to understand explanation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Proper notation is $r^2$, not $r²$, and $r\cos\theta$, not $rcos\theta$. And one can write $3\times5$ or $3\cdot5$; there is no need for $3*5$, which is a workaround for occasions when one is limited to characters on the keyboard. I edited accordingly.

Comment: I have replaced in the title "volume of a lemniscate" by "volume generated by a revolving lemniscate", because a lemniscate, per se, has no volume...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to integrate from $x=0$ to $x=3$. But if you want $x=0$, you need $\theta=\pi/4 \Rightarrow \cos(2\theta)=0 \Rightarrow r=0$. And if you want $x=3$, you need $\theta=0 \Rightarrow \cos(2\theta)=1 \Rightarrow r=3$. By the way, also for the surface area the "natural" choice would be $x=0$ to $x=3$, i.e., $\theta=\pi/4$ to $\theta=0$.